# Window display table and buffer display table conflict in Emacs

Tags: emacs

*In Emacs;*

Is there a way for both `window-display-table` and `buffer-display-table` to have effect at the same time?

The reason is, I'm using *Pretty-Control-L* (from *Emacs Goodies El* script package) and *whitespace* (of `whitespace.el`, I think it is in the base Emacs distribution, but I’m not sure).

- ***Pretty-Control-L*** visualizes form-feeds (`^L`) in a customized manner, by setting the entry for `C-l` in the window-local **`window-display-table`**.
- ***Whitespace*** visualizes spaces, tabs and newlines by setting entries in the buffer-local **`buffer-display-table`**. (and also by using `font-lock` functionality).

These uses clashes (or rather, the use of a `window-display-table` and `buffer-display-table` clashes) since, if the `window-display-table` is non-`nil` it completely overrides any `buffer-display-table` for any buffer displayed in that window.

Quote from the *Emacs Lisp* manual:

> ### 38.21.2 Active Display Table
>
> Each window can specify a display table, and so can each buffer.  When
>   a buffer B is displayed in window W, display uses the display table
>   for window W if it has one; **otherwise**, the display table for buffer B
>   if it has one; otherwise, the standard display table if any.  The
>   display table chosen is called the "active" display table.
>
> [...]

(emphasis by me)

So, Is there any easy way to consolidate this? Or is the only way to re-code one of them to use the same mechanism as the other?

I've been considering writing a small (i.e. even smaller) crude variant of the form-feed visualization compatible with the white-space visualization that just uses some buffer-loading hook (or other) to put a hard-coded entry for `^L` in the `buffer-display-table`. But I’d like to know if there’s any simpler alternative.

---

**EDIT:** To clarify the problem, here's a excerpt of an annotated "Interactive Lisp" session (i.e. from the `*scratch*`-buffer). This shows the commands and their output, and annotated with the effects:

```el
;; Emacs is started with `-q', to not load my init-file(s).

;; First, write some sample text with tabs and line-feeds:

"A tab: and some text
A line-feed:and some text"
;; Make sure that it is a tab on the first line (input by `C-q TAB')
;; and a line-feed on the second line (input by `C-q C-l').
;; These probably won't copy properly into Stack Exchange.

;; This shows the spaces as center-dots, tabs as `>>'-glyphs and
;; new-lines as $'s (or perhaps other glyphs, depending on system
;; setup...). All of them fontified to be dimmed out on yellow/beige/white
;; background.
(whitespace-mode t)
t

;; This turns on pretty-control-l mode. The `^L' above will be
;; prettified...  Since this sets the window display table, the glyphs
;; for the spaces/tabs/new-lines will disappear, but the background of
;; spaces/tabs will still be yellow/beige (since that's done with
;; fontification, not display tables).
(pretty-control-l-mode t)
t

;; This turns pretty-control-l mode OFF again. The form-feed will
;; revert to displaying as `^L'. However, the glyphs for the
;; spaces/tabs/new-lines will not re-appear, since this only removes
;; the `C-l'-entry in the window-display-list, not the entire list.
(pretty-control-l-mode 0)
nil

;; Nil the window-display-table, to verify that is the culprit.  This
;; will re-enable the glyphs defined by whitespace-mode (since they
;; are still in the buffer display-table).
(set-window-display-table nil nil)
nil

;; To round of; this is my Emacs-version:
(emacs-version)
"GNU Emacs 23.4.1 (i686-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 2.24.12)
 of 2012-09-22 on akateko, modified by Debian"

;;End.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for your trouble. I don't see the problem you report, following your recipe. Perhaps the description is not complete? I can turn on both `pretty-control-l-mode` and `whitespace-mode`, and the behavior I see for each seems normal.  Perhaps there is some custom setting you use for `whitespace-style` or something?

Anyway, maybe it would help if you make a change like this to `pretty-control-l-mode`. If so, let me know and I will apply it to [`pp-c-l.el`](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs-en/download/pp-c-l.el).  (To test, set the new option to `nil`.)

```
 (defcustom pp^L-use-window-display-table-flag t
   "Non-nil: use `window-display-table'; nil: use `buffer-display-table`."
   :type 'boolean :group 'Pretty-Control-L)

 (define-minor-mode pretty-control-l-mode
     "Toggle pretty display of Control-l (`^L') characters.
 With ARG, turn pretty display of `^L' on if and only if ARG is positive."
   :init-value nil :global t :group 'Pretty-Control-L
   (if pretty-control-l-mode
       (add-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'refresh-pretty-control-l)
     (remove-hook 'window-configuration-change-hook 'refresh-pretty-control-l))
   (walk-windows
    (lambda (window)
      (let ((display-table  (if pp^L-use-window-display-table-flag ; <=========
                                (or (window-display-table window)
                                    (make-display-table))
                              (if buffer-display-table
                                  (copy-sequence buffer-display-table)
                                (make-display-table)))))
        (aset display-table ?\014 (and pretty-control-l-mode
                                       (pp^L-^L-display-table-entry window)))
        (if pp^L-use-window-display-table-flag                     ; <=========
            (set-window-display-table window display-table)
          (setq buffer-display-table display-table))))
    'no-minibuf
    'visible))
```

---

**UPDATED to add comment thread**, in case comments get deleted at some point:

> BTW, I wonder if the hierarchy of display tables described in the doc shouldn't perhaps be applied using inheritance of some kind. Seems a bit primitive for one level (e.g. window) to completely shadow a lower level (e.g. buffer). You might consider sending a question about this to M-x report-emacs-bug. – Drew Sep 24 '14 at 16:36
>
> Ping? Could you please let me know if the change above helps? Thx. – Drew Oct 14 '14 at 18:12
>
> I just read this answer (I have not been around this part of the Internet for a while...). I will check this when I get round to it, perhaps in a few days or so. I'll get back with an ‘Answer approved’ (if it works), or comments (otherwise), as appropriate, later. – Johan E Oct 25 '14 at 22:32
>
> I edited the question to add a more fleshed-out recipe for showing the problem. I'd be interested whether you get the same results. --- Also, is there a way to shadow a system installed .el-file with a user-supplied one (I'm really just a “user”, not a lisp-programmer...)? I don't really feel like messing with the files installed by deb-packages. (That's why I did the problem-recipe before testing your answer...) – Johan E Oct 27 '14 at 1:02
>
> Five seconds after I wrote the last comment I realized that I could just paste the code into *scratch* and C-j-run it to test. (No need to edit any files.) The results: It works a charm! Thank you! (=> Answer accepted) However, I'd still like to know if you get the same results as I from my problem-recipe (before patching the code). – Johan E Oct 27 '14 at 1:09
>
> I just followed your new recipe, and I saw everything you described (so clearly). And then I read the new comment that you just added. Glad to know that things work OK. Thx for your feedback. – Drew Oct 27 '14 at 1:12

Comment: BTW, I wonder if the hierarchy of display tables described in the doc shouldn't perhaps be applied using *inheritance* of some kind. Seems a bit primitive for one level (e.g. window) to completely shadow a lower level (e.g. buffer).  You might consider sending a question about this to `M-x report-emacs-bug`.

Comment: Ping? Could you please let me know if the change above helps? Thx.

Comment: I just read this answer (I have not been around this part of the Internet for a while...). I will check this when I get round to it, perhaps in a few days or so. I'll get back with an ‘Answer approved’ (if it works), or comments (otherwise), as appropriate, later.

Comment: I edited the question to add a more fleshed-out recipe for showing the problem. I'd be interested whether you get the same results. --- Also, is there a way to shadow a system installed `.el`-file with a user-supplied one (I'm really just a “user”, not a lisp-programmer...)? I don't really feel like messing with the files installed by `deb`-packages. (That's why I did the problem-recipe before testing your answer...)

Comment: Five seconds after I wrote the last comment I realized that I could just paste the code into `*scratch*` and `C-j`-run it to test. (No need to edit any files.) The results: **It works a charm!** Thank you! (=> Answer accepted) *However, I'd still like to know if you get the same results as I from my problem-recipe (before patching the code).*

Comment: I just followed your new recipe, and I saw everything you described (so clearly). And then I read the new comment that you just added. Glad to know that things work OK. Thx for your feedback.